# Using touchstart fires click event after page redirect

Tags: javascript, events, touch, dom-events, touch-event

I have a touchstart event that is being fired properly, but inside the event, there is a redirect to another page. On that page, in the same location as the button that was touched, there is a link that is also being fired.

The event fires an ajax call that redirects on success. Everything is working properly aside from the issue of the ghost touchstart. Is there an easy way to deal with this issue? Or maybe a not easy way to deal with it?

Comment: Hi. I've the same issue here. I'm using touchstart events to hide the containing div and show another div with some input fields. The input field which is located at the same position like the element on the first page with the touchstart event gets the focus, imidiatly when the new view is loaded. I tried it with 
e.stopPropagation();
  return false; in the event-function but it is not working. Can anyone help?